# How to fix etl1 bug to update stock data?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

i am trying to make an etl1 to download daily data from yhaoo finance and upload new data in a sqlite db. The system is able to create correctly the db if there is not, and the first data upload. But when is necessary to make an update, it does not work. I think the problem is in some condition, and probably a date format.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import sqlalchemy
from engine.utils import clean_asset_string

class DataDownloader():
        
    def __init__(self, ASSET='TSLA'):
        self.ASSET = ASSET


    def download_and_save_data(self,interval='1d'):

        period = '10y'
        if interval[-1] == 'h':
            period = '719d'

        logging.info("Data download in progress")

        
        data = yf.download(tickers=self.ASSET, period=period, interval=interval)
        data.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

        


        if interval[-1] == 'h':
            data = data.reset_index()
            data['Date'] = data['Datetime']
            data['Date'] = data['Date'].astype(str)
            data['Date'] = data['Date'].str[:-6]
            data = data.set_index('Date')
            cols_to_delete = [
                'Adj Close', 
                'Datetime',
                ]
        else:
            cols_to_delete = [
            'Adj Close', 
            ]
        data = data.drop(columns=cols_to_delete)

        #managing last available date. We want candles when markets has generated them.
        last_date_available = data.index[-1]
        #print('last_date_available', last_date_available)

        current_date = datetime.now() 

        if interval[-1] == 'd':
            current_date = current_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            if isinstance(last_date_available, str):
                last_date_available = datetime.strptime(last_date_available, '%Y-%m-%d')


        elif interval[-1] == 'h':
            current_date = current_date.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            if isinstance(last_date_available, str):
                last_date_available = datetime.strptime(last_date_available, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                

        if current_date == last_date_available:
            data = data[:-1]
        elif current_date < last_date_available:
            raise Exception("Something is wrong with dates during download. Please verify with data provider.")


        self.ASSET = clean_asset_string(self.ASSET) #special characters create problems in db
        #print(self.ASSET)

        #when we switch to db
        file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        data_folder = 'staging1_download\\'
        database_file_name = 'staging1_download.sqlite'
        databasePathName = os.path.join(file_dir, data_folder, database_file_name)


        if interval[-1] == 'd':
            tableName = 'staging1_download_DailyData'
        elif interval[-1] == 'h':
            tableName = 'staging1_download_HourlyData'


        #print(databasePathName)
        #print(os.path.isfile(databasePathName))

        data["ASSET"] = self.ASSET
        data["INTERVAL"] = interval

        #if not os.path.isfile(databasePathName):
            #engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{databasePathName}')

        engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{databasePathName}', echo=True)
        if not sqlalchemy.inspect(engine).has_table(tableName):
            data.to_sql(tableName, con=engine, index=True)


        else:
            con = engine.connect()
            query = text(f""" 
            SELECT * 
            FROM {tableName}
            WHERE ASSET=:asset AND INTERVAL=:interval_value
            """)
            
            storedData = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=con, params={'asset': self.ASSET, 'interval_value': interval})

            if storedData.shape[0]==0 or storedData.empty:            
                data.to_sql(tableName, con=engine, if_exists='append',  index=True)

            else:
                
                availableDates = storedData["Date"].to_list()
                #print('availableDates', availableDates)
                availableDates = pd.to_datetime(availableDates, format='%Y-%m-%d')
                #storedData.index = storedData.index.astype(str)
                #availableDates = availableDates.astype(str)

                dataToStore = data[ ~storedData.index.isin(availableDates) &(self.ASSET==storedData["ASSET"].unique()[0]) & (interval==storedData["INTERVAL"].unique()[0]) ]            
                dataToStore.to_sql(tableName, con=engine, if_exists='append',  index=True)

        

        
        logging.info("Data download executed")
```

I think the problem is in here:

```
                availableDates = storedData["Date"].to_list()
                #print('availableDates', availableDates)
                availableDates = pd.to_datetime(availableDates, format='%Y-%m-%d')
                #storedData.index = storedData.index.astype(str)
                #availableDates = availableDates.astype(str)

                dataToStore = data[ ~storedData.index.isin(availableDates) & (self.ASSET==storedData["ASSET"].unique()[0]) & (interval==storedData["INTERVAL"].unique()[0]) ]            
                dataToStore.to_sql(tableName, con=engine, if_exists='append',  index=True)
```

But anything i did, does not work.
Any idea?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre].